# n-body problem: at least one point mass approaches spatial infinity as t -> ∞

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, potential

given an n-body problem $n>1$ and $T+U>0$, I have to prove that at least one of these n point masses approaches spatial infinity as time goes ad infinitum.
I was given the advice to first show the relation:

$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{m_i}{2}\vec{r_i}^2 = 2T+U $

which was rather easy, however I don't know how to continue. I am a mathematician and not that used to physical thinking yet. Any ideas on what I should consider for solving this problem?

Thanks

Comment: This actually may not be true. Imagine a central potential of the form $U = U(r) = \alpha r^2$, the total energy $T + U > 0$, and still all orbits are bound

Comment: $U(r)$ should be the gravitational potential, I guess.

Comment: Can't u use the equipartition theorem at this point. As $t\rightarrow\infty$ the system will obtain equilibrium an such that the right hand side goes to 0 ?

Since it will never happen that all particles are at rest \vec{ri} will never be constant such that the right hand side can only be constant if one of them is $\infty$ ?

The argument needs some refining but I would start there...

Answer (score 0):

Let $R = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{m_i}{2}\vec{r_i}^2$ .

Then
$\frac{d}{dt} (\frac{d}{dt}R - t(T+U))  = \frac{d^2}{dt^2} R - (T+U) = T \ge 0$ and therefore $lim_{t \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{d}{dt}R = +\infty$ and therefore $lim_{t \rightarrow +\infty} R = +\infty$.

So at least one $\vec{r_i}$ has an accumulation point at $+\infty$ .

However I can't show that $lim_{t \rightarrow +\infty} \vec{r_i} = +\infty$ for at least one $i$ .